# Concating files with Sublime?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, concatenation

I have a stack of `*.js` files. I want Sublime to concat them in one file by pressing a hotkey. Can't find a plugin to do such things. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/marcneuwirth/SublimeConcat

Comment: I've tried it, but have an error while concating file like this: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 408: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Go through them all(the files that error out) and make sure they are saved as the same type of encoding, otherwise right a script to do it, or write a macro in ST2 that opens, selects all, copy, then paste in the next file, so the last file will have everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (the unicode error), with the same package.

So I did an update that is merged into the repo.

What it does is that it unicodes the file content before inserting it into the concatinated file. It solved the issue for me, so try updating the package:

https://github.com/marcneuwirth/SublimeConcat