# Merge text files in Sublime4 like append?

Tags: windows, concatenation, sublimetext, appendfile, merge-file

Yes, I want just [combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971420/combining-files-in-notepad) files as simple as that:

**File1.txt**

```
line1
line2
line3
```

**File2.txt**

```
line4
line5
line6
```

I want to open the above two files at once and receive **File3.txt** in a new tab like this

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

It's odd that Sublime cannot do such simple operation. I found only [this old 10yo question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899906/concating-files-with-sublime) which is for Sublime2 so useless.

Can't Sublime 4 do this?

Comment: Can't you just `cat File1.txt File2.txt > File3.txt` instead? It will save lots of your time and mental efforts trying to do this inside your text editor.

Comment: I am in Windows, so no, I can't. And no, I do not want to install [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) just for that trivial operation.

Comment: Answers[here](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat) suggest that Powershell accepts `cat`, if not - there is direct analogous command.